# OPENJSON does not get recognized in Azure SQL DB

Tags: json, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I want to use `OPENJSON` function in Azure SQL DB, but when I try to execute the function, I get the following error:

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 25 'OPENJSON' is not a recognized
>   built-in function name.

I had researched and found this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) saying

> The OPENJSON function is available only under compatibility level 130 or higher. If your database compatibility level is lower than 130, SQL Server can't find and run the OPENJSON function. Other JSON functions are available at all compatibility levels.

As suggested, checked compatibility level with following

```
select * from sys.databases
```

and confirmed it was 140 which is higher than the minimum requirement.

So, wouldn't it it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OPENJSON is a table-valued function, and it must appear in the a valid location for a table expression.

EG

```
select openjson('{}')
```

fails with

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 29 'openjson' is not a recognized
>   built-in function name.

But

```
select * from openjson('{}')
```

works.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, it should work if the compatibility level is 130 or above.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2018/03/24/lesson-learned-34-does-azure-sql-database-support-openjson/

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

Three steps may help you:

1.Check your SQL Server version(Starting with 2016).

2.Check your Azure SQL database ompatibility level is 130 or higher.

3.Check your Azure SQL Database version.
Run `select @@version` to see if it is the V12 server.

If you see some lower version (e.g. 11.xxx) you probably have database on old architecture where JSON is not supported. You need to update your Azure SQL Database to the latest V12 version.

Reference:[OPENJSON does not work in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36470782/openjson-does-not-work-in-sql-server)

Hope this helps.