# SQL query to search a String without key, in a Column which has only JSON data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to search a string, for example '**RecId**' in a column which has only JSON data.

**First Cell JSON Data:**

{
    "AuditedFieldsAndRelationships": null,
    "AuditObjectChanges": false,
    "CalculatedRules": {
        "AuditHistoryDescription": {
            "Calculated": "Always",
            "CalculatedExpression": {
                "Description": null,
                "FieldRefs": ["**RecId**", "Rel_CIComponent_InstalledApplication_Name", "Rel_Software_Id", "Rel_Software_Name"]
            }
        }
    }
}

**Image:**

[image]

**Database**: Microsoft SQL Server 2014

**I got pretty similar problem solution in** [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47239225/how-to-search-sql-column-containing-json-array) **but it is with respect to key**

SELECT * FROM @table CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(Col,'$.Key') WHERE value ='SearchedString'

**but it is showing error Invalid object name 'OPENJSON**'

For that error, I tried the below solution given in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36470782/openjson-does-not-work-in-sql-server)

SELECT compatibility_level FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'DataBaseName';

**But getting the below error:**

[image]

Could someone help me out here.

Comment: `OPENJSON` was introduced with SQL Server 2016; you can't use it in 2014. If you really need to use `OPENJSON` then you need to upgrade. Otherwise you'll likely want to go down the CLR route, or use something else to read your JSON data.

Comment: Compatibility level = 130 is sql server 2016.

Comment: JSON support was added in SQL Server 2016. Trying to use `OPENJSON` in 2014 is never going to work. The best you can do, without getting really complicated, is to just use `value LIKE '%String%'` if you don't need to be specific about where the value occurs. If you do, good luck.